# codigniter where_in query working only first value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

CodeIgniter `where_in` query working only first value. Database field type is `varchar(255)`. Using `where_in` only work for first option - like if value is `1,2` then query is working for `1` and `1,2`, whereas for `2` its not working. If value is `2,1` then `2` is working and `1` stopped working.

Where query is like this:

```
$this->db->where_in('b.deal_available_city',explode(",",$this->input->cookie('city', TRUE)));
```

Comment: tried with that also like - $this->db->where_in('b.deal_available_city',array(2)); which is not working but $this->db->where_in('b.deal_available_city',array(2,1)); or $this->db->where_in('b.deal_available_city',array(1,2)); and $this->db->where_in('b.deal_available_city',array(1)); is working. Is there any issue with field type?

Comment: can you show use the output of `print_r(explode(",",$this->input->cookie('city', TRUE)))`?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 1
)

Comment: then use implode instead of `explode()`. I am confused. sorry. can you let us know the value of `$this->input->cookie('city', TRUE)` exactly?

Comment: First the issue which i am facing if i am passing value array(1) then showing result but `b`.`deal_available_city` IN('1') is not working. May be some quote issue is there or field type

Comment: @santanu  show us the exact value of `$this->input->cookie('city', TRUE)`

Comment: your commented on my post  after i get downvote .so i thought .you made it . it's okay no issue cool .  @AlivetoDie

Comment: the value $this->input->cookie('city', TRUE) is 1

Comment: yeah okay cool @AlivetoDie

Comment: so if it have one value then it will check only one value. So what's the problem?

Comment: if your column is varchar your value should be enclosed by single quotes inside the array

Comment: @AlivetoDie it's not working , showing 0 result but array(1) - without quote is working

Comment: @JYoThI it's not working , showing 0 result but array(1) - without quote is working

Comment: try this one first . $array= array('1', '2');
$this->db->where_in('b.deal_available_city', $array); @santanu

Comment: @JYoThI not working

Comment: can you show the sample data of table with deal_available_city column @santanu

Comment: please check the image - http://imgur.com/a/MPe5F

Comment: You need to trim values on insert. In one case there is `1,2` and in other one there is `1, 2`.

Comment: where_in will not work with your data @santanu

Comment: try this $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$this->input->cookie(\'city\', TRUE)',b.deal_available_city)!=",0);

Comment: What is the value of `$this->input->cookie('city', TRUE)`?? Can you just print that and check??

Answer (score 0):

you should use array like this:

```
$numbers= array('1', '2', '3');
$this->db->where_in('b.deal_available_city', $numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

After saw your data. where_in will not work . you need to use `FIND_IN_SET` .

```
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('1,2',b.deal_available_city) !=",0);
```